# I want to use double for loop in openpyxl

Tags: for-loop, openpyxl

I'm making a program that organizes revenues by year and quarter.

```
retyear() list type, Source file data  with information of year = [2009, 2017, 2019, ,2020, 2021, 2022, 2099]
shtcount=len(retyear)
shtcount2=(len(retyear)*5)
```

---------------------------------problem code--------------------------------------

```
wb2 = openpyxl.load_workbook("/Users/GiraffeMan/Desktop/02.xlsx", data_only=True)
file = "/Users/GiraffeMan/Desktop/02.xlsx"
ws2 = wb2['Summary']
for t in range(3, shtcount2, 5):
    for p in range(0, shtcount):
    print(retyear[p])
    ws2 = wb2.active
        ws2.cell(row=2, column=t, value="%dQ1" % retyear[p])
        ws2.cell(row=2, column=t+1, value="%dQ2" % retyear[p])
        ws2.cell(row=2, column=t+2, value="%dQ3" % retyear[p])
        ws2.cell(row=2, column=t+3, value="%dQ4" % retyear[p])
        ws2.cell(row=2, column=t+4, value="%dY Total" % retyear[p])
    wb2.save(file)
```

- [code : print(retyear[p]) -> Works Fine!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORD8H.png)
- [code : double for loop -> Work Strangely...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vjzpo.png)

double for loop only extracts the number 2099... Why?

Comment: Make sure you indent the code after the second for loop.

Comment: In fact, i indented the second for loop. It still doesn't work though.